# How to capture (record) video stream that enters to my browser?

Tags: java, html, flash, video, video-streaming

Imagine you watch sports live in your browser. It means you receiving a video stream, right? I need to record this stream and save to disk. The problem is that I don't have a clue from where to start. I'm not new to programming, but have a little experience in live video streaming. 
I see this problem divided into this parts:

1) Parse html page and find live source URL. (? sounds silly, I'm not sure it is easy to find URL)
2) When I have URL everything else becomes easy. I would use Java for example, to receive and record stream.

So the main problem is to find live source URL. Does anybody know how to do that?

a) From HTML5 video player

b) From flash player

Answer (score 1):

I  had similar concerns before the best think I can suggest would be ;
For the first option : 
open browser developer tools or wireshark and monitor the network while watching the video this is the most efficient way of locating the video source than you can just download the stream from the link

The second option :
there are some java libraries(jentpcap,jpcap ) for capturing ip packets after capturing the network adapter a while, you can filter them by type such a mpeg and get destination url note:some servers are sending these video samples as fragments you might need to merge them after downloading.

one more suggestion is gstreamer , as far as I know it has java wrappers and it is very useful for recording live videos  to a file.

Comment: after decompiling flash player  stream source url possibly can  be found in source code this work a few times for me

Answer (score 1):

If the sport you are watching has any sort of value then it will most likely be protected by DRM and you will not be able to do what you are suggesting on your PC/laptop.

You can still capture the file but as it is encrypted you won't be able to play it back.

If it is not protected by DRM then finding the URL from the source can work - it depends on the video file type and whether the server is using any sort of authentication before mapping the URL sent from the browser to the URL of the actual video.

You also likely need to understand the type of URL - not all videos play in all devices, and some video URL's actually point to a manifest or 'index' file which then contains the actual URL's for the individual video and audio streams.